# Django logger is logging logs with two different time , sometime in GMT and sometime in IST

Tags: python-3.x, logging, timezone, django-3.2

Django logger is logging logs with two different time, sometime with GMT and sometime with IST. IST is the localtime. Setting has not been changed between these two logs.

django logger from settings is printing these two logs in file:

```
2021-04-19 06:30:00,061 DEBUG  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
2021-04-19 12:00:20,061 DEBUG  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

django settings files contains:

```
    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

    TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

    USE_I18N = True

    USE_L10N = True

    USE_TZ = False

    LOGGING = {
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': False,
        'formatters': {
            'verbose': {
                'format': '{asctime} {levelname} {name}.{funcName}: {lineno}  {message}',
                'style': '{',
            },
            'simple': {
                'format': '{levelname} {message}',
                'style': '{',
            },
        },
        'handlers': {
            'file': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
                'when': 'midnight',  # this specifies the interval
                'backupCount': 10,  # how many backup file to keep, 10 days
                'filename': '/xxx/django.log',
                'formatter': 'verbose',
            },
        },
        'loggers': {
            '': {
                'handlers': ['file'],
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'propagate': True,
            },
            'django': {
                'handlers': ['file'],
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'propagate': True,
            },
        'django.db.backends': {
                'handlers': ['file'],
                'level': 'DEBUG',
            },
            'django.template': {
                'handlers': ['file'],
                'level': 'INFO',
                'propagate': True,
            },
        },
    }
```

Comment: I also facing the same issue.